# How to define sharding range for each shard in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

let say, the document is

```
{
  x:Number
}
```

and I have 3 shards.

Instead of autosharding, can I define specifically shard1 only contains data x<0, shard2 only contains data 0 =< x =< 1000 , and shard 3 is 1000

Answer (score 10):

You can. It's possible to pre-split chunks manually, it's described here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Splitting+Chunks

Think carefully about how you split your chunks. If you do it badly you can get lots of performance problems, but if you know enough about your keys you can gain a lot.

If you do it you probably want to turn off the balancer:

```
> use config
> db.settings.update({_id: "balancer"}, {$set: {stopped: true}}, true);
```

(this is described here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Administration)

This is an example of how you might do it. Depending on exactly what you want to do you will have to modify it (I assume your shard key is not named `x`, for example, and your range isn't -1000 to 2000).

```
> use admin
> db.runCommand({split: "my_db.my_coll", middle: {x: 0}})
> db.runCommand({split: "my_db.my_coll", middle: {x: 1000}})
> db.runCommand({movechunk: "my_db.my_coll", find: {x:   -1}, to: "shard_1_name"})
> db.runCommand({movechunk: "my_db.my_coll", find: {x:    0}, to: "shard_2_name"})
> db.runCommand({movechunk: "my_db.my_coll", find: {x: 1000}, to: "shard_3_name"})
```

The `split` commands create the chunks. Each command splits the chunk containing the middle value into two, so the first splits the chunk containing `min_value -> max_value` into `min_value -> 0` and `0 -> max_value`. Then the second command splits the chunk containing 1000, the second chunk created by the previous command, into two new chunks. After that command you have three chunks:

- `min_value -> 0`
- `0 -> 1000`
- `1000 -> max_value`

The three following commands moves these chunks to separate shards. The docs say that the command will move the chunk containing the value in `find`, so I picked three values I know are in different chunks and used these (there is a symbol in BSON for `min_key` and `max_key`, but I'm not sure how to use it properly in this context).

Read this page too http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Moving+Chunks

Comment: for my particular example, how to set it?

Comment: Follow the first link and look at the first example.

Comment: The first example is splitting into two set evenly using "middle".  I have read all three examples but not sure how to do the sharding as I mention above. :(

Comment: I've added an example. Make sure to read _all_ documentation under sharding in the Mongo docs, it's very helpful.

Comment: What if I want to split on the bases of string e.g. A-F on Shard1, F-K on Shard2 and K-Z on Shard3. Any reference material or answer will do. Thank you